# How to expose global object like @User in razor views?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

How/Where can I declare an object like @User so that it can be referenced globally in any razor view using @?

Something similar to:

_LoginPartial.cshtml:

```
@if(Request.IsAuthenticated) {
    <text>Signed In As  <strong>@User.Identity.Name</strong> |
```

but instead reference my object:

```
  @if(this && that) { <text>@MyObject.GetData</text> }
```

Comment: Are you asking how to do @User?  Or are you asking how to do @MyOwnObject?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can change the base type of a Razor page to a one of your own eg:

```
public class UserAwareViewPage : System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage
{
  public IPrincipal User { get { return Thread.CurrentPrincipal; } }
}
```

And then modify your config file like so:

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
  <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, 
  System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, 
  Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
  <pages pageBaseType="Your.Namespace.UserAwareViewPage">
    <namespaces>
      <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
      <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
      <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
      <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    </namespaces>
  </pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```

Phil Haack has a very good [blog post on this here](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/02/21/changing-base-type-of-a-razor-view.aspx).

Alternatively, you can add an extension method to `System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage` (the base type for razor pages) and use this.

```
public static IPrincipal User(this System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage page)
{
  return Thread.CurrentPrincipal;
}
```

Which would be useable like so:

```
@if(Request.IsAuthenticated) {
<text>Signed In As  <strong>@User().Identity.Name</strong>
```

Personally, I prefer the first approach, but thought I'd provide the second for an alternative option.

Comment: 'SharedViewPage' does not implement inherited abstract member 'System.Web.WebPages.WebPageExecutingBase.Execute()

Answer (score 4):

The `@` syntax isn't referencing values in any way, it's just telling the view engine that you're beginning a server-side code block.

There's nothing "global" about it.  In this case, `User` is a property on the `System.Web.WebPages.WebPageRenderingBase` abstract class, which [is used by the view engine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.webpages.webpagerenderingbase%28v=vs.99%29.aspx) when rendering views as [they inherit from it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.webviewpage%28v=vs.98%29.aspx).

I suppose you can extend the `WebViewPage` or the `WebViewPage<>` classes to add properties to them.  There may be a better way to achieve what you're trying to do without modifying those, though.  If you're trying to pass data to the View, shouldn't that data be part of the ViewModel?

Ideally you'd supply everything the View needs in a custom ViewModel and the View would inherit from `WebViewPage<CustomViewModel>`.

In Razor syntax I think you'd begin the CSHTML with something like:

```
@model CustomViewModel
```

Then you'd access properties on that using the `Model` property:

```
@Model.SomeProperty
```

Answer (score 2):

You could probably do something like this in your View:

```
@Html.ViewContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name
```

I would recommend against that however, and add this information to a ViewModel. For example:

```
public ActionResult SomeController()
{
    var model = new MyViewModel
    {
        Username = User.Identity.Name
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

Now inside the view you can display this information:

```
@Model.Username
```

Answer (score 2):

Or for a less obtrusive approach, and this works for any Razor page simply the default:

```
@Context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated
```

Sure you could setup a quick variable alias if you like at the top of your Razor file (_Layout or otherwise):

```
@{
  var User = Context.User;
}
```

but really unnecessary unless you have a custome `IPrincipal` object in that case:

```
@{
  var User = (MyAuthenticatedUser)Context.User;
}
```

and that works and is what I use :)

Comment: Being new to ASP MVC's Razor, it sort of had skipped my mind that I could just dynamically introduce "globals" or custom objects into a view using the simple approach like what you show in your second example. Thanks!